# Finding minimum non-zero value across multiple columns in dataframe R

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I'm trying to find the lowest non-zero value in my dataset using this for loop:

```
smallest_nonzero_values <- c()
for (i in 1:length(colnames(df))){
  i <- 1
  column <- df[,i]
  column <- column[column!=0]
  smallest_nonzero_values[i] <- min(column)
}
```

The code works, but somehow it doesn't loop through all columns and stops at col 1 and just gives me output: Inf.

I'm quite new to R and know that for loops are not recommended, but I don't know how else to find this when looking at more than one column. Thanks!

Comment: `max(mtcars)` for max value in whole data frame, similar for min.

Comment: Thanks, but using min(df) just gives me 0.

Comment: In the future check the manual, `max(mtcars,na.rm=T)`. If you want to remove zeros then simply subset the data frame to only include non zero elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the zeros to NA, then calculate the `min` ignoring NAs:

```r
library(tidyverse)

tribble(
  ~x, ~y, ~z,
  20, 0, 1,
  0, NA, 0,
  40, 20, 0,
  10, 30, NA,
) |> 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ if_else(. == 0, NA_real_, .))) |> 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ min(., na.rm = TRUE)))

#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>       x     y     z
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    10    20     1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>